# misconfigured SSL using webhooks

Tags: ssl, github, ssl-certificate, webhooks, githooks

I have created an http server to receive post-hooks from git whenever a push event is issued (for the purpose of auto-deployement).
The problem is that when I add a Web hook to my repository , and when an event is triggered, the request cannot reach the server.

And I get the following error:

```
We had a problem connecting to the server.  
The most common problem with these types of errors is a misconfigured SSL Certificate .
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

By default, a GitHub WebHook would perform SSL certificate verification

[image: http://steve-jansen.github.io/images/2014-12-03-A.png]

(and disabling that verification is not a good idea)

Make sure your server has all intermediate CAs in its keystore, and debug your certificate using an [SSL checker](https://cryptoreport.websecurity.symantec.com/checker/) as mentioned in "[Troubleshooting GitHub WebHooks SSL Verification](http://steve-jansen.github.io/blog/2014/12/03/troubleshooting-github-webhooks-ssl-verification/)".

Comment: I tried to send switching https for http ,  but still give me the same error ?

Comment: Yes it needs https, which means your server must start listening with a valid SSL certificate